# Firebase Device group messaging to thousands of users

Tags: android, ios, .net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We built firebase device group functionalities into our app's back-end. This permits us to message users on all of their devices. According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group), to send a message to a device group, we have to make a request to the firebase with the notification key. So if we have to send to multiple devices, what we do is; loop through the list of notification keys for each of the 4000 users and send a message to each user with their notification keys.

This approach obviously is very slow, since thousands of web requests are made to the firebase API.
So, while implementing this push notifications functionality on our API using Firebase cloud Admin SDK, we didn't find any form of "topic" messaging for device groups.

My question is: does someone know a more efficient way of sending push notifications to device groups other than looping through these notification keys and sending multiple web requests?

This is how I send a message to a device group.

```
    public async Task<SendDeviceMessageResponse> SendNotificationToDevices(DeviceMessage message)
    {
        var resultStr = await Post(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message), FirebaseSendMessageURL);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SendDeviceMessageResponse>(resultStr);

        if (result.FailureCount == 0 && result.SuccessCount == 0)
        {
            result.ResponseType = ResponseType.EmptyDeviceGroup;
        }
        else if (result.FailureCount > 0 && result.SuccessCount > 0)
        {
            result.ResponseType = ResponseType.PartialSuccess;
        }
        else if (result.FailureCount == 0 && result.SuccessCount > 0)
        {
            result.ResponseType = ResponseType.TotalSuccess;
        }
        else
        {
            result.ResponseType = ResponseType.TotalFailure;
        }

        return result;
    }


    private async Task<string> PostToFirebaseDeviceGroup(DeviceGroupRequestModel requestModel)
    {
        string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestModel);
        var respStr = await Post(body, BaseFCMNotificationsURL);
        return respStr;
    }
```

The complete implementation of the above [is found in this repository](https://github.com/coolc0ders/FirebaseCloudMessagingWithDotnet/tree/main/Firebase.Notifications/Firebase.Notifications/Firebase).

When I have several device groups I have to send a message to, I loop through the device groups, and call the above "SendNotificationToDevices" for each device group. That is what makes it slow. whereas, with "Topic" messaging, I just need to make a single request to the API and that is all. Is there some form of topic messaging for Device groups ? or a more efficient way of sending thousands of messages?

Comment: "This approach obviously is very slow" Keep in mind that **everyone** is using this exact same API to send notifications to their (Android) users. So while your implementation may be obviously slow to you, the API isn't inherently slow and is actually incredibly scalable. There's a good chance we can help better if you show the minimal code that reproduces the slowness you experience in sending messages, and the timings that you get from that code.

Comment: All I do, is; send a post web request exactly as what is seen here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#device-group-http-post-request The only difference is that I do it for about 3000 users. The messages are sent, but the time it took is about 6minutes.

Comment: Hello @FrankvanPuffelen I updated the question with code, and a link to the complete source code I use on github.

Comment: When you call `SendNotificationToDevices`, are you awaiting each individual response? I'd recommend doing a reasonable number of calls in parallel, as the FCM backend is set up to handle massive parallel loads anyway. The other way to speed things up is to send batched messages as those can pipeline over HTTP/2 and amortize the cost of establishing the connection over multiple calls. But I'm not sure what API you're calling, and whether device groups are even supported i the versioned API that supports such batch calls.

Comment: This is what I'm calling : https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send